# How to determine the sign conventions when two masses are attached via pulley when one of them on inclined plane?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, coordinate-systems, conventions

How to solve this question

> Mass m1 moves on a slope making an angle θ with the horizontal and is attached to mass m2 by a string passing over a frictionless pulley. The co-efficient of friction between m1 and the sloping surface is x. Show
>   If box m1 has to slide up the plane then 
>   m2 < m1sinθ + xm1cosθ?
>
> Please provide a complete detailed solution with sign conventions and using Newton's laws of motions.

I tried doing but got really confused with the signs. As they are in different direction hence I dont exactly how to choose the coordinate system. If i try to do them as individual direction ie 
For m2 up is positive

And for m1 right along the inclined plane is positive. Then I end up with exact opposite answer?

Comment: -1. For such exercises the site policy is that you must **show your attempt** to solve the problem and **ask about a conceptual difficulty**. Being confused by your own use of a sign convention  is not a conceptual difficulty.

Comment: Well im asking conceptually why do we take sign as positI've in direction of string not according to coordinate system ? And now here what about the sign of g ?

Comment: In one case we are taking g positive and other g is negative.

Comment: Does this qualify as conceptual doubt ? @sammygerbil

Comment: If you apply any sign convention consistently, and interpret the answer according to the same convention, you will get the same answer.

Comment: I know that but I did the same but ended up with opposite in one dimensional it is easy but with pulley confusion arises ?

Comment: Review your solution. It is likely that you did not use the sign convention consistently. If one direction is $+x$ you should use the same direction for $+\dot x$ and $+\ddot x$. When working with strings which change direction, you need to measure distances *along the string*. In David Elm's diagram, if the 7kg truck moving right has +ve velocity, then the 3kg moving down has +ve acceleration, and the gravity force on the 3kg block is also +ve. ... The problem is (effectively) 1D not 2D, because the pulley does not move.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pulley system. Why do I need to put a minus sign?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/272791)

Answer (score 2):

The positive direction follows the direction of the string.  Once you establish a positive direction (it doesn't matter which way) to be consistent, that positive direction can be determined by looking at how the string goes.

[image]

For instance, in a situation here,

if we have the positive direction for the 7 kg mass is to the right,

then following the string, the positive direction is downwards for the 3 kg mass.

If you look at the diagram, when the car is moving to the right, then the hanging block is moving downwards. Also, when the car is accelerating to the right, then the block is accelerating downwards.

My advice is to draw a picture of your scenario and make sure you are consistent.

The reason why the positive direction follows the string is subtle, but simple: The direction of the string gives you the particular direction of motion.

Since the acceleration is the change in that motion, and the force is parallel to the acceleration, using the direction of the string helps line everything up nicely.

Comment: Why do we take it according to the string. And what if the 7 kg mass is on inclined plane ?

Answer (score 0):

**Lets do it step wise-**

1)Since m1 is just about to move up then frictional force will act in downward direction along the the plane.

2)The tension in string will be equal to (M2)g because of equilibrium of M2.

3)M1 will experience gravitational force (M1)g*sinθ in downward direction.

4)Now since we got all the forces lets try to see what effects sign conventions will have on solution.

**When upward direction along plane is taken positive**

Net force on M1= M2g-M1gsinθ -M1gxcosθ

Now for upward movement, net force should be positive as per present conventions
Therefore,

```
  M2g-M1gsinθ -M1gxcosθ>0
=>M2>M1sinθ + M1xcosθ
```

Hence proved.

**When upward direction along plane is taken positive**

Net force on M1= M1gsinθ + M1gxcosθ - M2g

Now for upward movement, net force should be negative as per present conventions
Therefore,

```
  M1gsinθ + M1gxcosθ - M2g<0
=>M2>M1sinθ + M1xcosθ
```

**Observation-**
It doesnt matter which side you take positive or negative in sign conventions as the answer will get different sign according to convention but it will imply the same direction.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to think about it is that the direction of motion *for the entire system* is the positive direction.  The system as a whole is moving up the inclined plane and then downwards.

For M1, the positive direction would be up the inclined plane, and the negative direction would be down the plane.

For M2, the positive direction would be downwards, and the negative direction would be upwards.

What I would suggest doing is treating both masses as one entire system.  Find the forces acting on both masses (using the sign convention above), and find the net force from that.  Then, add up the masses of both objects to find the sum - this is the mass *of the system as a whole*.

At this point, you can divide the total net force of the *system* by the total mass of the *system* to find the acceleration, for example.  If you end up with a negative sign, that means the system moves in the direction that it shouldn't (so your answer is probably wrong).  If you end up with a positive sign, the system accelerates up the plane and downwards (since that's the expected direction of its motion).

Hope that helps.