# How can we know direction of blocks in pulley systems?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, acceleration, free-body-diagram, string

How can we find the direction of acceleration in pulley systems so that we can write equation of motion for different parts of the pulley system. Do we have to assume acceleration in some particular direction?

Comment: You may just assume the acceleration to be x in a particular direction. If x comes out to be -ve, you know that it was in the opposite direction.

Comment: There is a systematic approach to these kinds of problem.  Short version: represent each object as it's own dynamic system, and find out how they are all coupled or constrained.  Choose different frame for each one; the signs of the variables are arbitrary, the dynamics will tell you if your object moves in the opposite direction to your "positive".   I [wrote an answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/272841/5739) that gives a simple example.  This technique is both instructive and useful.   There's no other way in complex systems.

Answer (score 0):

You choose a direction of positive acceleration and work with this direction consistently.

If the acceleration turns out to be negative then you know it is in the opposite direction to direction you chose.

Answer (score 0):

Block A suffers a constant deceleration given by:

$$ \frac{\text{d}v_A(t)}{\text{d}t} = -\mu  g, \qquad v_A(0) = v_0,\ [v_A(t)>v_B(t)]$$

This acceleration lasts as long as block A does not reach the end of B. On the other hand, block B experiences an acceleration to the left given by:

$$\frac{\text{d}v_B(t)}{\text{d}t} = +\mu \frac{m_A}{m_B}g, \qquad v_B(0) = 0,\ [v_A(t)>v_B(t)]$$

Because the force $F_{A\to B} = +\mu m_A g$. The differnetial equations predict that if B is long enough, both velocities will equalize and thereafter the two blocks will move together. The generalized principle of conservation of energy (including frictional losses) allows to calculate the final of the set of two blocks (this velocity is reached only if B is sufficiently long):

$$\frac{m_A}{2} v_0^2 = \frac{(m_A+m_B)}{2} v_f^2 + \mu m_A g x_A$$

where:

$$x_A = v_0t_f-\mu \frac{g t_f^2}{2}, \qquad v_f = v_0 -\mu g t_f >0$$

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it depends upon the force, that resultant force acts in which direction like, take this example If pulley is hanging from a rigid support say roof and masses are connected as shown in figure given below.
(assumption: block m2 is heavy then M)
[image]

Fbd becomes [image] now as you seen in diagram, how the resultant force shows the direction of acceleration of body.

Comment: Isn't there a more suitable way to find out direction rather than looking at figure and figuring out direction of acceleration?

Comment: Logic behind the direction is force, it depends upon you, how fast you analyze the situation,  which block should go down and which should go up.